# How to Export data from db2 with Complex SQL query via db2 commandline?

Tags: sql, db2, export

I have complex SQL Query and I want to export data (csv files) with these SQL via db2 commandline and must include  these format  "xxxxx","aaaaaa","cccccccc"

sql query I save in .sql file

what's command?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to export data from DB2, you need to use the 'export' command.
For example, for a table called employees you will execute

```
db2 "export to myFileName.csv of DEL select * from employee"
```

If you need to include strings in you query, you can put single quotes around the word.

In order to execute this, you need a DB2 client, invoke the db2clp, and be connected to the database.

```
In windows: Run
db2cmd
db2 connect to sample
```

For more information, please consult the InfoCenter: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html

Comment: thank you, this was super helpful